# Change widget of GTK Box

Tags: python, matplotlib, gtk, glade

I have 3 figure canvas, 3 buttons and a GTK Box. I first initialize the box with one canvas and I want to change widget of the box whenever I click a button:
[image]
Here is the pseudocode

```
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtk3agg import (
    FigureCanvasGTK3Agg as FigureCanvas)
from .file import canvas1,canvas2,canvas3
@Gtk.Template(resource_path='/org/example/App/window.ui')
class CovidtrackingWindow(Gtk.ApplicationWindow):
      dose_by_day = Gtk.Template.Child()
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.dose_by_day.add(canvas1)
@Gtk.Template.Callback()
    def on_1month_btn_clicked(self,button):
         self.dose_by_day.add(one_month_dose_canvas)
```

Comment: Why not use a GtkNotebook? https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/Notebook.html#Gtk.Notebook

Comment: Tks I did not know about GtkNotebook